# How to hide certain files in Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Using Microsoft's Visual Studio Code, how do I hide certain files and file patterns from appearing in the sidebar?

I want to hide .js and .js.map style files

I am using visual studio code for angular 2 projects.

And I want to only show .ts files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add file with name .gitignore and add the below contents:

```
        **/*.js
        **/*.js.map
        node_modules
        dist
        typings/**
        debug.log
        launch.json
        npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you add this file to your root directory? it is working fine for me.